# Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework

When I am trying to set the state then getting an error.
**Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.**

```
const Money= (props) => {
     // some states and functions
      .
      .
      /
     const [loss, setLoss] = useState('');
     const [gain, setGain] = useState('');

     const diffrenceInCount = (todayCount as any) - (yestarDayCount as any);
        // (todayCount(6) and yestarDayCount(24) are my some states which holds the respective values)
        //diffrenceInCount = -18

        if (diffrenceInCount < 0) {
          const moneyLoss = diffrenceInCount.toString();
          setLoss(moneyLoss );
        }
        if (diffrenceInCount > 0) {
          const moneyGain = diffrenceInCount.toString();
          setGain(moneyGain);
        }

       useEffect(() => {
         userMoney();
         allUserMoney();
       }, [])

 return (
      <IonContent>
       {* some code *}
      </IonContent>
      );
}
export default Money;
```

I have tried it with the `useReducer` and I am looking for a solution for setting the state.

Comment: your code snippet here doesn't show your problem, the issue is likely to be in your `render()` method or a `useEffect()` call

Comment: @Nathanael in ```useEffect()``` I am making the functions call.

Comment: So...did you want us to guess what `userMoney()` and `allUserMoney()` do? There are lots of questions about this error (as seen in the Related list to the right). Do none of those give you a hint as to the problem?

Comment: the second parameter should prevent useEffect() from entering an infinite loop, so there must be something in the return() code that is updating the state

Comment: ```if (diffrenceInCount < 0) {
          const moneyLoss = diffrenceInCount.toString();
          setLoss(moneyLoss );
        }
        if (diffrenceInCount > 0) {
          const moneyGain = diffrenceInCount.toString();
          setGain(moneyGain);
        }

```

these lines are always setting state... You should put them in function and it should only run on any event you want

Comment: @Cavdy thanks, i already tried this approach because i want to set the these states on first rendering, so i have put that function inside the ```useEffect``` but i was still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (diffrenceInCount < 0) {
      const moneyLoss = diffrenceInCount.toString();
      setLoss(moneyLoss );
    }
    if (diffrenceInCount > 0) {
      const moneyGain = diffrenceInCount.toString();
      setGain(moneyGain);
    }
}, [diffrenceInCount]);
```

You should try this... It only runs when there are changes in `diffrenceInCount`